# Cant get my program to run - %GC calculator

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have been trying for a few weeks not to get this program running. I am newer to programming and it has definitely been a challenge. I think my problem arises with my if statement. I can get it to append the name to the new file, but it simply appends the whole sequence to the file rather than counting it. I am working with a fasta file that contains multiple sequences, the name starting with '>' and the sequence on one line below it. Here is my code. Please help, and thank you so much in advance!!

```
#! /bin/bash

#exit program with error if user does not specify input on command line

if [ $# != 1 ]; then
        echo "Please specify fasta input on command line and rerun"
        exit
        else echo "Beginning count"
fi

#collect input from user each time they run the program
input=`cat $1`

#seperate the sequence from the sequence name
name=`grep '>' $1`
sequence=`grep -v '>' $1`


#if name, if sequence
IFS=$'\n'
set -f
for i in $(cat "$1"); 
do
    if [ $i=">" ]; then
        echo "$i" >> GCcontent.txt
        else 
        #count number of occurence of motif ATGC in fasta sequence
        countG=`echo $i | grep -o "G" | wc -l`
        countC=`echo $i | grep -o "C" | wc -l`
        total=`echo $i | wc -m`
        count=`echo "scale=2" ; ($countG+$countC) | bc`

        #calculate percent over total divided by 3bp
        percent=`echo "scale=2 ; ($count/$total*100)" | bc`

        #print output name and percent to file
        echo "$percent" >> GCcontent.txt
    fi
done

echo "Exiting"

exit
```

Edit: 
Input file: (there are no quotes around >, it would not let me put it in there without them)
'>'gi|226451773|gb|FJ846591.1
CATTATAGACTGCGTGGTCCGTATTCCCAAGGAGCAGGGAGTTCTGTCCTTCTGGCGCGGTAACCTGGCCAATGTCATCAGATACTTCCCCACCCAGGCTCTTAACTTCGCCTTCAAAGATAAATACAAGCAGATCTTCCTAGGTGGTGTGGACAAGAGGACCCAGTTTTGGCGCTACTTTGCAGGGAATCTGGCATCAGGTGGTGCCGCAGGGGCCACATCCCTGTGTTTTGTGTACCCTCTTGATTTTGCCCGTACCCGTCTAGCAGCTGATGTGGGTAAAGCTGGAGCTGAAAGGGAATTCCGAGGCCTCGGTGACTGCCTGGTTAAGATCTACAAATCTGATGGGATTAAGGGCCTGTACCAAGGCTTTAACGTGTCTGTGCAGGGTATTATCATCTACCGAGCCGCCTACTTCGGTATCTATGACACTGCAAAGGGTAAGTTTGCTGTGGGCTTTAAAGTTGTGTTCTTAGGAGACAATTTAAAAGAGCGTTGTACCAACCTAACATTCCAAGAGCTAGAGAGTTTTTTTAATTGCTGAAGGAAGCCAAGATCATCCAGTGCGACCCTCATGCACAGATGACATGTTTAGGGGATGTGGGGAAAGGAAGTCAGTAAAACTCTACTTTTTGGTAAAAGCATCTCTTTCCTATTCCCAGGAATGCTTCCGGATCCCAAAAACACTCACATCGTCATCAGCTGGATGATCGCACAGACTGTCACTGCTGTTGCTGGGTTGACTTCCTATCCATTTGA
 (but multiples of these in the files)

I would like the output file to have:
'>'gi|226451773|gb|FJ846591.1 
'Percent would go here'

Comment: you need white space around equal sign. `$i = ">"`.  I also suggest you look into `awk` where you'll have more expressive power of a programming language.

Comment: Please post a sample input file with enough details and expected output for the same.

Comment: Run your code through shellcheck.net first to identify the more obvious problems.

Comment: I've tried that, but i'm not sure if it will work. I can't insert my input file for it to run

Comment: Insert `echo` commands to inspect variables values as your script run. For example `echo "countG=$countG"`. Then you will be able to spot the place when things go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

using your input file (line) here is a proof of concept

```
$ awk '{s=length($2); 
        g=gsub("G","",$2); c=gsub("C","",$2); t=gsub("T","",$2); a=gsub("A","",$2);
        total=a+c+g+t; 
        print a,c,g,t,total,100*(c+g)/total,total==s}' file

185 175 190 209 759 48.0896 1
```

the last value `1` checks the total matches sum of individual matches.

You want to apply the logic to lines prefixed with `>` sign

```
$ awk '/^>/{...; print $1, 100*(c+g)/total}' inputfile > outputfile
```

copy over the relevant sections from above to fill the gap.

In case you have lines without any match, total will be zero and division will fail.  You can add a guard.

The complete script can be like this

```
 $ awk '/^>/{g=gsub("G","",$2); c=gsub("C","",$2); total=length($2);             
             print $1, (total?100*(c+g)/total:"no match found")}' inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: how would i got about appending the name before the value in the new file without using a loop? This is my major issue to the code.

Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: `awk` has an implicit loop running through all lines, you don't need an explicit one.  Were you able to try this script?

Comment: I added a guard for zero but you didn't copy the pattern exactly.  If your data file is consistent I'll start with checking the pattern first and if still fails add the guard.

Comment: Also you haven't copied to code into the `...` section.  There should be one awk script.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new at this. I am getting there though. I tried the completed script and i can populate the output file, but all lines repeat "no match found"

Comment: My fault, I dropped the total, which is fixed now. If you want to validate, you may still want to check all other bases and compare the values in case you have some extra chars in the second field.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is what I wrote: 
    #! /bin/bash

```
#exit program with error if user does not specify input on command line

if [ $# != 1 ]; then
    echo "Please specify fasta input on command line and rerun"
    exit
    else echo "Begining count"
fi

#collect input from user each time they run the program
input=`cat $1`

awk '/>/{...; print $1, 100*(c+g)/total}' $input > GCcontent.txt

awk '{s=length($2); 
    g=gsub("G","",$2); c=gsub("C","",$2); t=gsub("T","",$2);           a=gsub("A","",$2);
    total=a+c+g+t; 
    print a,c,g,t,total,100*(c+g)/total,total}' "$1" >> GCcontent.txt
```

This is what i get back:

Beginning count

awk: />/{...; print $1, 100*(c+g)/total}

awk:     ^ syntax error

awk: cmd. line:3: (FILENAME=sample.fa FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted